# Comment, PRATIQUEMENT, respecter les règles complexes d'usage des «, », ", ', “, ” en tapant sur un clavier soit AZERTY, soit QWERTY ?

Tags: ponctuation, typographie

**Le respect des règles (qui demandent plusieurs pages de définitions, imposées par qui ?)** conduit à des exemples cocasses, comme celui pêché sur le site canadien :
http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/ponctuation-punctuation/guillemets-quotation-fra.html

> Mon père m’a dit : « À l’école, l’institutrice écrivait souvent sur mes devoirs : “Beau travail ‘bonhomme’, c’est *super*.” »

De plus, il paraît que les guillemets français : `«` et `»` doivent être accompagnées d'un blanc, mais pas les anglais : ni `“` ni `”`.
Hélas, je n'ai rien de tout ça, sur mes claviers Azerty et Qwerty. D'où la nécessité de taper <kbd>Alt</kbd> suivi d'un code.
J'utilise donc systématiquement : `"` ; mais cela m'a valu des reproches.

**Question donc : ne peut-on admettre la simplification précédente quand le sens est évident ?**

Pour aggraver mon cas de rébellion : j'encadre systématiquement mes signes de ponctuation par deux blancs, sauf la virgule et le point, trouvant le texte nettement plus lisible.

Comment: Voir aussi http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/235/176

Comment: Je trouve que pour des textes électroniques de tous les jours l'utilisation de guillemets autres que " complexifie la vie sans apporter grand-chose. De plus les éditeurs de texte présents dans les logiciels de type Outlook ont la fâcheuse habitude de mal gérer le copier-coller des guillemets. Mais bon, je ne suis pas un puriste non plus.

Comment: Chercher à éviter tout reproche est la meilleure recette pour tourner fou ;-) Adopte des règles cohérentes entre elles et adaptées à l'environnement où tu t'exprimes, et laisse-les froncer les sourcils sans inquiétude.

Comment: *"mais cela m'a valu des reproches."*
Des reproches, ou juste des éditions de posts?

Comment: Encore une fois aucune question n'est clairement formulée. Comment utiliser un clavier sur tel OS c'est hors sujet sur FL&U. Demander si la simplification est acceptable, pourquoi pas, mais quel type de réponse attends-tu ? « Oui » ou « non » ? Ça me parait de peu d'intérêt et très « opinion-based », si tu vois ce que je veux dire…

Comment: Encadrer les signes de ponctuation double par des espaces (certaines sont des espaces fine lorsque c'est possible) ce n'est pas de la rébellion c'est l'usage.

Comment: Je recommande une nouvelle fois la lecture de l'[aide](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), même si Laure a déjà mentionné ce point. Cette question frôle à la fois le « I use __ for __, what do you use? » ou le « __ sucks, am I right? ». De plus le ton est celui de « let's participate in a discussion about __ », je t'invite à lire la section « constructivisme » sur cette même page.

Comment: Je présente mes excuses pour une erreur du ... site cité (j'ai rectifié). La correction complète par un modérateur de compétence indéniable, oui, je l'ai prise comme un reproche, et ai douté du bien-fondé de ma question. J'aimerais bien, lorsque l'on tape un commentaire, avoir la correction d'orthographe - je fais souvent des fautes matérielles - et surtout les outils d'OpenOffice. Mais je ne sais même pas y faire un retour à la ligne, c'est déjà parti.

Comment: Oui, pardon j'aurais du préciser « en France », au Québec l'usage de la ponctuation diffère légèrement.

Comment: En ce qui concerne les guillemets, lorsque j'ajoute une clarification un tag ou quoi que ce soit qui mérite d'être amélioré, j'ai l'habitude de corriger tous les petits détails insignifiants de mise en forme en même temps. Il ne faut pas y voir un reproche, c'est l'approche recommandée sur l'ensemble des sites Stack Exchange.

Comment: « Ne peut-on admettre la simplification précédente quand le sens est évident ? » dans quel cadre ?  S'il s'agit de ce site, la place pour poser ce genre de question est la partie « meta ».

Comment: Attention, le terme « clavier AZERTY » n'est pas assez précis. Sous Windows, le comportement est différent du comportement sous Linux, ou encore à celui de MacOS. Par exemple, les guillemets («, ») se tapent facilement par [AltGr + w] et [AltGr + x] respectivement sous Linux. La plupart des caractères sont donc disponibles facilement.

Comment: C'est avant tout une question sur l'utilisation des éditeurs et traitements de texte, pas sur la langue française. La réponse est qu'il suffit de savoir se servir de son ordinateur. Au passage `“…”` est acceptable en typographie suisse et québecoise si je me souviens bien (mais pas `"…"` : même en anglais, les guillemets ouvrants et fermants ne sont pas identiques).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily about using computers, and inasmuch as it is about French typography, it is imprecise and wholly subjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voici un petit logiciel gratuit développé par Denis Liégeois qui me rend de grands services.

http://accentuez.mon.nom.free.fr/Clavier-Liegeois.htm

Comment: La question n'est pas « comment taper des caractères de ponctuation sur mon système d'exploitation favori ? ». C'est hors-sujet pour FL&U.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Ceci permet de respecter les règles en question sur un clavier AZERTY. Ce qui répond bien à la question posée.

Comment: La réponse à cette question-là dépend de plusieurs paramètres dont notamment le système d'exploitation et la méthode de saisie. Elle a sa place sur [su] (ou éventuellement en tant que FAQ sur notre [meta]), mais pas ici.

Comment: Plussoyé pour le lien : le titre de la question comprend le mot "PRATIQUEMENT", ce que fait M42

Comment: Pour moi, la question est : « Question donc : ne peut-on admettre la simplification précédente quand le sens est évident ? ». Je suis tout à fait d'accord avec @StéphaneGimenez.

Comment: @Maxime: merci pour le vote négatif. Cela répond à la question du titre : « Comment, PRATIQUEMENT, respecter les règles complexes ... ». Et, d'ailleurs, cette réponse à été acceptée.

Answer (score 1):

Deux façons de s'en prendre aux problèmes de typographie électronique :

- les laisser aux puristes, et faire de son mieux avec le clavier à disposition,
- se donner les moyens de l'élégance en paramétrant un éditeur de texte.

Lire des courriels tapés sur des claviers *qwerty* sans accents me gêne énormément, et je lis beaucoup plus facilement un mauvais accent (*é* à la place de *è*) que le manque d'accent pour (j'etais a Paris cet ete, j'ai achete…)

**Pratiquement**, il y a des éditeurs libres de qualité, comme *[LibreOffice](http://fr.libreoffice.org/telecharger/)* et *[OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/fr/about-downloads.html)*, où l'on peut paramétrer ses préférences typographiques, comme par exemple le remplacement des `"` par des `«` et des `»` assortis des espaces fines  appropriées

On peut aussi y ajouter un correcteur orthographique (toujours libre) comme *[Dicollecte](http://fr.libreoffice.org/telecharger/)* et réaliser des documents où le formatage typographique donnera une esthétique graphique à une présentation sans faute d'orthographe … cela peut être favorable pour un curriculum vitæ.

---

L'exemple tiré du wikébec facilite  la compréhension du texte : lorsqu'un texte a intégré la typographie dès sa conception, la supprimer le rend très difficile à lire (inélégance et non-respect du lecteur).

> Mon père m’a dit : "À l’école, l’institutrice écrivait souvent sur mes
>   devoirs : "Beau travail "bonhomme", c’est super.""

Comment: Démonstration de l'intérêt des correcteurs orthographiques : "me gène énormément" n'est évidemment pas dû à l'ignorance mais à une distraction, et j'y suis si sujet qu'ils m'aident bien !

Comment: Ou utiliser le clavier bépo qui permet de taper tous les caractères du français et de nombreuses autres langues http://bepo.fr

Comment: @Impair J'y ai pensé, mais il exige un changement radical des habitudes de frappe et éventuellement un achat supplémentaire pour un clavier ergonomique (que l'on doit toujours transporter avec soi ?), alors que le lien donné dans la réponse de M42 exige beaucoup moins d'adaptations.