# Guillemets imbriqués

Tags: ponctuation

La phrase suivante de Proust est extraite du site [alarecherchedutempsperdu.com](http://alarecherchedutempsperdu.com/marcelproust/317).

> Car le nouveau domestique aux pieds plus rapides, et déjà familiarisé
>   avec ces expressions, nous ayant répondu que « si Madame n'était pas
>   sortie elle devait être à la « vue de Douville », « qu'il allait aller
>   voir », il revint aussitôt nous dire que celle-ci allait nous
>   recevoir. (Version 1)

Je l'ai trouvée écrite d'une manière légèrement différente dans mon édition de poche Gallimard, page 454 : les guillemets entourant "vue de Douville" sont des guillemets anglais.

> Car le nouveau domestique aux pieds plus rapides, et déjà familiarisé
>   avec ces expressions, nous ayant répondu que « si Madame n'était pas
>   sortie elle devait être à la "vue de Douville", « qu'il allait aller
>   voir », il revint aussitôt nous dire que celle-ci allait nous
>   recevoir. (Version 2)

Je suis choqué par un fait très simple, il y a dans cette phrase trois guillemets ouvrants mais seulement deux fermants. Considère-t-on que les guillemets fermants après "vue de Douville" comptent double ? Si oui je n'ai jamais vu un pareil cas. Ou s'agit-il d'une nième erreur dans les éditions de ce texte ?

Comment: Ca ressemble en effet plutôt à une erreur de typo. (ou du [terrorisme](http://xkcd.com/859/) ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La seule façon raisonnable de lire (et d'écrire) cette phrase est :

> Car le nouveau domestique aux pieds plus rapides, et déjà familiarisé avec ces expressions, nous ayant répondu que « si Madame n'était pas sortie elle devait être à la « vue de Douville » », « qu'il allait aller voir », il revint aussitôt nous dire que celle-ci allait nous recevoir.

D'aucuns jugent que le double guillemet fermant est inesthétique et suggèrent de n'en utiliser qu'un. Cet exemple est une parfaite illustration de leur déraison.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la raison de couper, puis de rouvrir la citation au niveau de la virgule. Le plus logique me semblerait être : *Car le nouveau domestique aux pieds plus rapides, et déjà familiarisé avec ces expressions, nous ayant répondu que « si Madame n'était pas sortie elle devait être à la « vue de Douville », qu'il allait aller voir », il revint aussitôt nous dire que celle-ci allait nous recevoir.*

Comment: J'imagine que l'auteur voulait faire transparaitre qu'il s'agit de deux citations différentes que le domestique n'a pas énoncées l'une à la suite de l'autre (grammaticalement ça ne peut pas se suivre). Je n'ai pas inventé le guillemet ouvrant avant *qu'il*, il était dans le texte original.

Answer (score 1):

Bien que marquée *closed* [Comment, PRATIQUEMENT, respecter les règles complexes d'usage des «, », ", ', “, ” en tapant sur un clavier soit AZERTY, soit QWERTY ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7882/comment-pratiquement-respecter-les-regles-complexes-dusage-des) donne, dans la question posée, un bon exemple de choix de guillemets imbriqués qui auraient dus être utilisés dans votre exemple, et les moyens de les réaliser.

Il semblerait que pour l'usage typographique, il ne soit pas possible de doubler deux fermetures simultanées (**» »**) dans une phrase.

---

*Edit après commentaire*

Ce qui donnerait :

> ... « si Madame n'était pas sortie elle devait être à la "vue de Douville" » ,  « qu'il allait aller voir » , ...

Comment: @cl-r contrairement au guillemets français, les guillemets anglais (ici ce sont des guillemets droits, mais passons) ne sont pas suivis (précédés) d'une espace.